# Cannot iterate the data from an array ref VUEJS

Tags: vue.js, supabase

I'm having a slight issue here when i try to iterate through the data array from "history" ref

[image]

[image]

As we see here, there is 2 console log, 1 from the request and 1 after we put the data in history both show 2 array which is what the values should be but there is nothing on the table and yes every row have an unique id in the database

I'm still pretty new to vuejs ^^

> **Template**

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <h3 v-if="loading"> Loading... </h3>
     <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Shares</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ref="history" v-for="row in history" :key="row.id" >
            <td>{{ row.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.shares }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.price }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</div>
```

> **Script**

```
<script>
import { store } from "../store"
import { onMounted, ref, reactive } from "vue"
import { supabase } from "@/supabase"

export default {
setup () {
    const loading = ref(true);
    const user = supabase.auth.user();
    const history = ref([])


    async function getHistory() {
        try {
            loading.value = true;
                let { data, error, status } = await supabase
                .from("history")
                .select(`id, user_id, title, shares, price`)
                .eq("user_id", user.id)


                console.log(data)
                if (error && status !== 406) throw error

                if (data) {
                history.value = data
                console.log(history.value)
                }
            } catch (error) {
                alert(error.message)
            } finally {
                loading.value = false
        }
    }

    onMounted(() => {
        getHistory()
    })
     
    return {
        loading,
        user,
        history,
    }
},

data() {
    return {}
}
}
```

Comment: This suggests there are no row.title, etc, but there could be black text instead. It doesn't matter what happens in a database, it matters what `data` is, you could reproduce it with static JSON. Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The data have a title, if i console.log(data[0].title) after queuing the database i'm getting the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is using `ref="history"` on the `tr` tag, as it will bind the `ref` with the DOM element, you need to remove it.

```
    <tr v-for="row in history" :key="row.id" >
        <td>{{ row.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.shares }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.price }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Ok that was the issue, for some reason ive seen some people using ref="" so i was guessing to put the ref variable inside. Thanks for clarifying it